# Launch a set of codes from a single bash file

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, gnome-terminal

I'm working on Ubuntu OS, I want to make a **single bash file** which runs this code correctly as it shows in the screenshots.

Please notice that :

- I want to launch two terminals in a single terminal window and the second set of codes in the second terminal should be launched after 5 seconds of the first set of codes in the first terminal.
- I need the first set of codes to keep running (do not stop when starting the second terminal).*

Code:

```
cd catkin_ws
roscore
sleep 5
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch hector _slam_launch tutorial.launch
```

Screenshots:

[image: Terminal 1]
[image: Terminal 2]

Comment: Please do not have pictures of text. Include all text in the body of the question.

Comment: Either way it needs to be in the question not as a picture.

Comment: I think the picture indeed is OK here because it to illustrate how the tabs should appear. However, you should *embed* it in the post itself. This forum has a function for that, which is powered by Imgur.

Comment: @Dark, any reason you changed your question to be like *"aze aze zaeaz eaze zaeaze eaz e az"*?

Answer (score 1):

It used to work, and for now will still work with the following code:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "sh -c 'cd catkin_ws ; roscore'" \
               --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 5; source devel/setup.bash ; roslaunch hector _slam_launch tutorial.launch'"
```

[Issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784925) is that the Gnome developers are considering dropping the `-e` ("execute") option, in favor of terminating your options with `--`, after which a command is supplied. They, however, forgot that this change makes that you only can provide a single command. It is not anymore possible to open Gnome Terminal automatically with multiple tabs containing different processes, for example each containing a different ssh session.

Comment: I usually test my answers, and running this from a script using the Alt+F2 prompt gives me neatly a new terminal window, "top" running in the first and the second waiting with a prompt, after `ls` was executed. Could not reproduce this with your applications, of course. However, I see that strangely, you refer to `sudo` in your comment. That was not there in your question. Obviously, you should not run gnome-terminal as root user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a terminal tab with `gnome-terminal --tab` command. Put the commands into a file and pass to `bash` as the `--initfile` parameter:

```sh
cd catkin_ws
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/roslaunch-script.XXXXXX)
cat >$tmpfile <<EOF
sleep 5
source "$HOME"/.bashrc
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch hector _slam_launch tutorial.launch
EOF
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash --init-file $tmpfile
roscore
rm $tmpfile
```

Comment: I can't test the entire script, but when I run this script from a `gnome-terminal` tab, `roscore` is started and a second tab is created which gives me `bash: devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory` error after 5 seconds.